# How to pass an useState to a Function from a Funtional Component?

Tags: react-native, use-state, setstate, react-functional-component

So for my college project, I need to make an app that can fetch data from a server and log in to the user.

for the login functional component this is the code that i have used,

```
const login = () =>{
let number= this.State.number;

if(number.length==0){
  alert("Required Field is Missing");
}

else{
  let api="http://127.0.0.1/Project18/login.php";

  let headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  let Data = {
    number:number,
};

fetch(api,{
  method:'GET',
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(Data)
})
.then((response) =>response.json())
.then((response)=>{
  alert(response[0].Message);
})
.catch((error) => {
  alert("Error"+error);
  })
}
 }

 function Login(props) {
 const [text, setText] = useState('');
 return (
  <View>
  <TextInput 
  style={{width:200,margin:10}}
  placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
  placeholderTextColor={"tomato"}
  onChangeText={number => setText(number)}
  defaultValue={text}
  ></TextInput>
  <Button 
  title="Login" 
  style={styles.loginButton} 
  onPress={login}
  >
  </Button>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
);
```

}

All I need to do is pass the '`setText(number)`' component to the `login()` function so that the

`let number=` gets its value.

I have very less idea about react native so I can't complete the project. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the login function inside the Login component.

```
function Login(props) {
 const [text, setText] = useState('');

 const login = () => {
   let number= text;
   if(number.length==0){
     alert("Required Field is Missing");
   } else {
     let api="http://127.0.0.1/Project18/login.php";
     let headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     };
     let Data = {
       number:number,
     };
    fetch(api,{
      method:'GET',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(Data)
    })
    .then((response) =>response.json())
    .then((response)=>{
      alert(response[0].Message);
      // use setText() here
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert("Error"+error);
    })
   }
 };

 return (
  <View>
  <TextInput 
  style={{width:200,margin:10}}
  placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
  placeholderTextColor={"tomato"}
  onChangeText={number => setText(number)}
  defaultValue={text}
  ></TextInput>
  <Button 
  title="Login" 
  style={styles.loginButton} 
  onPress={login}
  >
  </Button>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: this says, "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.State')

Comment: Is the number variable supposed to be the value of the text field? If yes, then I have changed the code, try again.

Comment: this is working, but it's not working on "button-press" as I keep typing it checks on every time the text is changed and keeps popping the alerts, and on correct number, logs in, but without even pressing the button

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `text` state to your `login` function as follows.

```js
function Login(props) {
 const [text, setText] = useState('');
 return (
  <View>
  <TextInput 
  style={{width:200,margin:10}}
  placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
  placeholderTextColor={"tomato"}
  onChangeText={number => setText(number)}
  defaultValue={text}
  ></TextInput>
  <Button 
  title="Login" 
  style={styles.loginButton} 
  onPress={() => login(text)}
  >
  </Button>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
);
```

Then use it in `text` as follows.

```js
const login = (text) =>{
   let number= text;
   ...
```

Comment: this is working, but it's not working on "button-press" as I keep typing it checks on every time the text is changed and keeps popping the alerts, and on correct number, logs in, but without even pressing the button